# php merging two images looks broken

Tags: php, gd

i am trying to merge two transparent images using php but image has some black border and spots i could not figure out issue below is my attached code

```
$image1=$image2='imagepath.png';
imagealphablending($image2, true);
imagesavealpha($image2, true);

$w=imagesx($image1);
$h=imagesy($image1);

$final = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);

$black = imagecolorallocate($final, 0, 0, 0);
$backgroundColor = imagecolortransparent($final, $black);

$percent = 0.583;
$new_width = $w * $percent;
$new_height = $h * $percent;
$wshift = $w/8.5;
$hshift = $h/2.5;
imagecopy($final, $image1, 0,0,0,0,$w,$h);

imagecopyresized($final, $image2,$wshift,$hshift,0,0, $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($final);

imagedestroy($image2);
imagedestroy($image1);
imagedestroy($final);
```

sample test :

see in action : http://goo.gl/qMWNB4

image url : http://goo.gl/pR59MT

Comment: This is neither a dashed border, nor a border at all actually. This happens because your images are low-resolution.

Comment: i tested with 300*300 px images same issue how to if it even with 600
*600 px same issue

Comment: The `imagecopymerge` may help a little. http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php

Comment: i tried that also anyway to fix issue

Answer (score 0):

OK so i've had a go and have managed to:

a) make a mess of your code :)
b) get rid of enough black that i'm sure you cna finish the job!

```
$image1=$image2=imagecreatefrompng('test1.png');
imagealphablending($image2, false);
imagesavealpha($image2, true);

$w=imagesx($image1);
$h=imagesy($image1);

$final = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);

$percent = 0.583;
$new_width = $w * $percent;
$new_height = $h * $percent;
$wshift = $w/8.5;
$hshift = $h/2.5;

$temp = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

imagecopymerge ($final, $image1, 0,0,0,0, $w , $h , 100);
imagecopymerge ($temp, $image2, 0,0,0,0, $w, $h, 100);

$black2 = imagecolorallocate($temp, 0, 0, 0);
$backgroundColor = imagecolortransparent($temp, $black2);

imagecopyresized($final, $temp,$wshift,$hshift,0,0, $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);

$black = imagecolorallocate($final, 0, 0, 0);
$backgroundColor = imagecolortransparent($final, $black);

imagepng($final, 'output8.png');
```

Hope you get there soon - back to the day job for me :)

Comment: I'm having another go now - making some headway. This is a fun task man!

Comment: Not usually, why do you have an offer? Have you managed to progress the issue?

Comment: yeh i am using ur code ,also i have some task if u are interested

Comment: bro but still image looks can can we fix it anyhow

Answer (score 0):

The black border is caused by using `imagecolortransparent`.  This is meant for palette based images, not true colour, and uses a single colour for transparency throughout the whole file instead of the alpha-value of each pixel.

The trick to get this to work is in setting the correct blending mode at the correct time:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('35477413.png');

$w = imagesx($img);
$h = imagesy($img);

$final = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
imagesavealpha($final, true);

$percent = 0.583;
$new_width = $w * $percent;
$new_height = $h * $percent;
$wshift = $w / 8.5;
$hshift = $h / 2.5;

// disable alpha blending so that transparent pixels replace target pixels.
imagealphablending($final, false);
imagecopy($final, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h);

// enable alpha blending so that transparent pixels blend with target pixels.
imagealphablending($final, true);
imagecopyresized($final, $img, $wshift, $hshift, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($final);

imagedestroy($img);
imagedestroy($final);
```

This gives the following output:

[image: result]